# In R, conditionally count IDs who meet an ANY condition on a certain attribute

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

**Background**

I've got a dataframe `df`:

```
> df <- data.frame(ID = c("a","a","a", "b", "c","c","c","c","d","d","d","d"),
                 treatment = c(0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1),
                 event = c(0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 
> df
   ID treatment event
1   a         0     0
2   a         1     1
3   a         1     0
4   b         0     0
5   c         0     1
6   c         0     1
7   c         0     1
8   c         0     1
9   d         0     0
10  d         0     0
11  d         0     1
12  d         1     0
```

It's got 4 people (`ID`) in it: a, b, c, and d. Each `ID` can have one record, like `b` does, or several records, like the other 3 do. They each have values for `treatment`, which is binary, and `event`, which is binary too.

**The problem**

I want to count how many distinct `ID`s who have ANY `treatment==1` or NO `treatment==1` ever (in other words, all `treatment==0`) also have `event==1` and `event==0`. Here's what I'd like the result to look like:

```
> [some R code]

event  treatment  n
    0          0  1           
    0          1  0
    1          0  1
    1          1  2
```

To break this out into English:

- `ID`s **a** and **d** and have got ANY `treatment==1` and ANY `event==1`
- `ID` **b** has got no `treatment` EVER and no `event` EVER
- `ID` **c** has no `treatment==1` ever (i.e. all `treatment==0`) but does have any `event==1` (as you can see, he's actually got ALL `treatment==1`)

**What I've tried**

I know I'm close, but the `dplyr` code I'm using is getting tripped up by the fact that `IDs` have rows with both `treatment==1` and `treatment==0`, and the same for `event` -- so `R` is double-counting everyone, showing me with 8 people instead of 4:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(event, treatment) %>%
  distinct(ID) %>%
  count(event) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  mutate(Percent = round((n/sum(n))*100, digits = 1))

  event treatment n Percent
1     0         0 3    37.5
2     0         1 2    25.0
3     1         0 2    25.0
4     1         1 1    12.5
```

I'm not married to `dplyr` on this, but it's what I'm most familiar with (as opposed to `data.table`, for instance). The real dataset this code is going to be run on has several million rows, just FYI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(treatment = as.numeric(sum(treatment) > 0), 
            event = as.numeric(sum(event) > 0)) %>%
  select(-ID) %>%
  count(treatment, event)

  treatment event     n
      <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1         0     0     1
2         0     1     1
3         1     1     2
```

Comment: Looks good on the example code, thanks @Park. Give me a few minutes to run it on my "real" dataset.

Comment: *data.table* translation for fun since you mentioned millions of rows - `df[, lapply(.SD, \(x) as.integer(any(x == 1))), by=ID][, .(n=.N), by=.(treatment,event)]`

Answer (score 3):

In base R:

```
data.frame(t(table(aggregate(.~ID, df, \(x)+(sum(x)>0))[-1])))

  event treatment Freq
1     0         0    1
2     1         0    1
3     0         1    0
4     1         1    2
```

Comment: Thanks @onyambu, but question: where in your code are the `treatment` and `event` columns indicated? I'm a spoiled `Tidyverse` user and base `R` novice.

Comment: @logjammin in the `.` part of the formula. If your data has alot of columns just subset the df ito the three columns you want ie `data.frame(t(table(aggregate(.~ID, df[c('ID', 'treatment', 'event')], \(x)+(sum(x)>0))[-1])))` or include them in the `.` part using `cbind`. Note that it is always good to learn base R functions

Comment: Ah yes, that was exactly the issue. Thanks so much! (And point taken on base R.)